# Running Virtual Machine through a Browser (as CGI)

Tags: browser, cgi, virtual-machine

I have some knowledge of CGI scripts and how they work and came to thinking that, in theory, it should be possible to run VirtualBox, or any type of virtualization as a CGI script. Understandably, this would be no easy task. For one thing, it's output (the screen of the virtual OS) would somehow have to be converted so that the browser could read it, show it to the user, and then somehow update it without refreshing the page (which would mean JavaScript would be involved, probably).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how one would start a project such as this one? Has this been done/attempted before?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... Why would you want to run a virtualized machine (computer) as a CGI script? I can understand wanting to run your web server ON a virtual machine, to make it more secure when it executes CGI scripts, but running IN a CGI script? Just out of curiosity, what would this be used for?

Comment: I would then be able to access the virtual machine from anywhere with internet access. More importantly, people visiting my site would also be able to do so. Ideally, the visitors would all access the same virtual OS (it wouldnt reboot between every refresh) and collaborate. It'd be an OS on the cloud

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense to me, I'm afraid. They make remote terminal software for allowing access to machines across a network, for every OS with which I'm familiar. Trying to implement this in CGI is simply silly (and would be pretty much impossible, given the way CGI interacts with a web server). Sorry, but I have to vote to close this as "not a real question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, running a virtual machine as a CGI script is highly unpractical, as it would stop the machine if the connection is broken. Instead, the CGI script should be able to start, stop and control the virtual machine, which would be running in the background.

As for interacting with the virtual machine, VirtualBox has support for remote desktops (through the VNC protocol), which is probably the most suitable method of displaying and controlling it. However, while you *can* use a combination of server-side and client-side scripting to make this work, this would probably become very slow and use a lot of bandwidth. Instead, you could use something like a Java applet to connect directly to the virtual machine via VNC, which would save much of the hasstle on the server side.

There is also a similar idea called [phpvirtualbox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/), which I haven't look into myself, but you might find it interesting.